# C++ error upon memory allocation

Tags: c++, arrays, memory, crash, allocation

I have a question about memory allocation in C++.

A lot of my programs were crashing without any foreseeable cause. When I started testing to find the cause, I came across something interesting.

The following code complies correctly and does not crash, when executed.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
char memblock[7200][140];
};
```

This code DOES CRASH

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
char memblock[7200][140][10];
};
```

This lead me to believe that adding the extra dimension was the cause of my woes. But, then I noticed that this code does not function either.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
char memblock[7200][1400];
};
```

It turns out that the number of dimensions in an array declaration has no effect on the functionality of the program. It appears as though there is a cap to the total amount of memory that can be allocated to the program. (I tried multiple smaller array declarations, but that did not work.)

Any instructions before the large array declaration execute perfectly. And Windows Task Manager tells me that there is no shortage of RAM or CPU power.

So, my question is: What is causing the program to crash? And, is there any way to fix (or circumvent) the problem?

Answer (score 2):

You are allocating these arrays on the stack. But the stack is a rather limited resource. With Visual C++ it defaults to 1 megabyte max size. Large arrays should instead be allocated in the heap.

Answer (score 0):

This line of code (which isn't standard c++ compliant BTW)

```
char memblock[7200][140];
```

asks to allocate `1008000` bytes on the stack, which is likely to be to big for what the stack size configured with your OS can hold.

Answer (score 0):

> And, is there any way to fix (or circumvent) the problem?

Since others gave answers on what the problem is, here is one solution: use a `std::vector`:

```
#include <vector>
//..
std::vector<std::vector<char>> memblock(7200, std::vector<char>(1400));
//...
```